# .htaccess rewrite rule for clean URL not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

htaccess rewrite rule which I am have trouble with. When I put the correct slug address in the URL (/page/1) I get undefined variable errors. Any help most appreciated.

HTACCESS

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ page.php?id?=$1 [NC,L]
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
require_once("db.php");
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT meta_desc, title, content, url_slug  FROM tbl_emp_details WHERE id=?");
    $sql->bind_param("i",$_GET["id"]);          
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {        
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $row["meta_desc"]?>">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

</head>

<body>
  <h1><?php echo $row["title"]?></h1>
  <div class="content">
  <?php echo $row["content"]?>
  </div>
```

The error I think is because I'm not putting this in page.php but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Add slash before `/page.php?id=$1`

Comment: What's the incoming URL, script location, access.log? And enable the RewriteLog for debugging. Please describe your error/observation in more detail. Might just be the **doubled `?`** in the rewrite target.

Comment: @mario Error log  [30/Sep/2018:16:35:32 +0100] "GET /page/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 3211

The errors are:
Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\wamp64\www\mysqli-template\page.php on line 29

3 of them where I am trying to echo out the page.
url errors when i have template.com/page/1